# extract (long, lat) from long address string in R

Tags: r, stringr

```
4517 bessie dr dallas, tx 75211 (32.728761, -96.895678)
3700 ross ave dallas, tx 75204 (32.797677, -96.786384)
```

I have a column in a dataframe that has values like listed above
i want to create a 2 new fields long and lat that have the values between `,`

this is what i have so far

```
data$longlat<-str_split(data$geocoded_column,sub("\\(.*", "", data$geocoded_column))
data$longlat<-str_sub(data$longlat,start=9)
which gives me 
32.728761, -96.895678)"
32.797677, -96.786384)"
```

Comment: Could you provide your data in a more accessible format? For example, if you call `dput(data)` then it should return a format which is easier to work with for potential helpers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i am pulling in r from socrata api https://www.dallasopendata.com/Public-Safety/Police-Incidents/qv6i-rri7/data
the column is the last one location1 but when pulled from the api it is named geocoded_column, does that help

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the values using `stringr` and lookaround:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "(?<=\\()[^(]+(?=\\))")
[[1]]
[1] "32.728761, -96.895678" "32.797677, -96.786384"
```

To get the values into a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  long = unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<=\\()[^(,]+(?=,.*\\))")),
  lat = unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<=, )[^(]+(?=\\))"))
)
df
       long        lat
1 32.728761 -96.895678
2 32.797677 -96.786384
```

Data:

```
x <- "4517 bessie dr dallas, tx 75211 (32.728761, -96.895678) 3700 ross ave dallas, tx 75204 (32.797677, -96.786384)"
```

Comment: thanks!! how to i get them into 2 columns one for each of those 2 values after that step?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(c1 = c('4517 bessie dr dallas, tx 75211 (32.728761, -96.895678)','3700 ross ave dallas, tx 75204 (32.797677, -96.786384)'))
df
                                                       c1
1 4517 bessie dr dallas, tx 75211 (32.728761, -96.895678)
2  3700 ross ave dallas, tx 75204 (32.797677, -96.786384)
df %>% extract(col = c1, into = c('lat','lon'), regex = '(-?\\d+\\.\\d+), (-?\\d+\\.\\d+)', remove = F)
                                                       c1       lat        lon
1 4517 bessie dr dallas, tx 75211 (32.728761, -96.895678) 32.728761 -96.895678
2  3700 ross ave dallas, tx 75204 (32.797677, -96.786384) 32.797677 -96.786384
```